# How to Grid two or more figures in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, grid-layouts

I am trying to combine the following two plots using Grid option. The problem in that in the combined figure, the Legends appear larger and spoil the look of the entire figure.

```
    legendPS1C1 = 
  With[{x = 0.005}, 
   LineLegend[{Directive[Blue, Thickness[x]], 
     Directive[Red, Dashed, Thickness[x]]}, {"Sin(x)", "Cos(x)"}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {{30, 2}}]];

legendPS2C2 = 
  With[{x = 0.005}, 
   LineLegend[{Directive[Purple, DotDashed, Thickness[x]], 
     Directive[Black, Dotted, Thickness[x]]}, {"Sin(x)", "Cos(x)"}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {{30, 2}}]];

A = Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[5 x]}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, {Red, Dashed, 
     Thickness[0.005]}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[legendPS1C1, Top], GridLines -> {{0}, {0}}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", Rotate["Sin(x), Cos(x)", 0 Degree]}]

B = Plot[{Sin[2 x], Cos[8 x]}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Purple, DotDashed, Thickness[0.005]}, {Black, Dashed,
      Thickness[0.005]}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[legendPS2C2, Bottom], GridLines -> {{0}, {0}},
   FrameLabel -> {"x", Rotate["Sin(x), Cos(x)", 0 Degree]}]

grid = Grid[{{A}, {B}}, Spacings -> {2, 2}]
```

Comment: Another way to see the problem is to consider that the plots should not be reduced in the combined figure. In that case the solution is : `grid =Style[ Grid[{{A}, {B}}, Spacings -> {2, 2}],ImageSizeMultipliers->{1, 1}]`

Comment: Thanks @andre. It worked for me.

Comment: see also: [ImageSizeMultipliers on mma.se](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=ImageSizeMultipliers)